# TEENSY 3.2 RS-232 throughput

Tags: serial, teensy

I have an application where I need 4 serial ports - 3 will be sending and receiving.  The packet size will be up to 255 bytes on these 3 "main" ports.  The 4th port will be receive only, and its packet size will be 6 bytes. There is no flow control. The data rate on all ports is 115,200 baud. The 3 main ports will send or receive data packets approximately once per second. Most data will be half-duplex, although occasionally it will be necessary to send and receive simultaneously from a port . The 4th port (the one that handles 6 bytes), will get packets at an approx 50 packets/second rate.

The TEENSY will have to calculate CRCs on all ports, and will have to do a small amount of data manipulation as well.

I was planning to use the hardware serial ports for the 3 main ports, and software serial for the port that has to deal with only 6 bytes.  It is important that the 3 main ports be able to not miss any incoming data.  The 4th port is less important and can "miss" a packet now and then with no ill effects.

Will a TEENSY 3.2 running 90MHz be able to keep up?

Answer (score 1):

Once per second? I don't see any problem, I will try to calculate:

3 ports: send + receive 255 bytes, let's say 270 bytes (with start/stop bits, probably way too much) per message:

3 * 2 (send + receive) * 270 = 1620 bytes
4th port: 50 * 6 bytes = 300 bytes

Total: 1920 bps

The serials can easily keep up with this, so that is not a problem.

90 MHz is 90 million instructions per second. As you can see, handling 1620 bytes is nothing ... it could do many more, a factor of multiple thousands more.

Unless of course you want to do heavily calculations for the received/sent data.